# Center img & h2 vertical in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, center, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align an image and an heading vertically. I'd like to do this in a table because is should be some kind of a menu. So there are more of this 'segments'. The img and the heading have to be in the same td-element for some further functionality of my menu...

I've tried **vertical-align: middle**, **display: inline-block** & **table-cell** and many things more. But nothing seems to work for me. The h2-element seems to ignore all of this thinks and stick to the top.

```
img{float: left; height:100px; width:auto}
td{width: 300px; verical-align:middle}

<table><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70">
            <h2>TEXT</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70">
            <h2>TEXT</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Here is a fiddle of my problem https://jsfiddle.net/0x48n7qL/

How do I archieve this? What am I missing out?

**EDIT:**
The actual size of the image and therefore the height of the row is relative to the size of the page so I can't use fixed height values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
img {height:100px; width:auto; vertical-align: middle;}
td {width: 300px;}
h2 {display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nr3j6Lco/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add to your h2 those properties :

```
line-height: 100px;
margin: 0px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0x48n7qL/1/